# No route to host on docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container that stopped working about an hour ago after working fine for years. It's a redis container and when I try to connect to it, it gives the error "Connection to Redis redis:6379 failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (113) No route to host" It stopped working after I restarted my computer and brought the container back up. Here is what I tried:

I checked `docker container ps` and confirmed that the redis container is running and it has the correct name.

I connected into the container and confirmed that the redis server is running in the container.

I turned off my firewall in case that was blocking something, even though I have rules that allow my containers to run, but it's still not working.

I ran `sudo iptables -S` and confirmed that the ip address and port for redis are Accepted.

I ran `docker network inspect util_devel` and confirmed that the redis service with the correct ip address was listed within the containers in the list.

I confirmed that the redis ip address was in my hosts file.

I also checked some of my other docker containers, like mysql, and they couldn't connect either.

I'm not sure what else to check. I'm still kind of a novice when it comes to docker. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Update: Here is the output of each of the checks:

docker container ps:

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
c6c56725172b        foobl/php:5.6-xdebug                                  "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp                                                                                     php56
fdc76ffe6efb        rabbitmq:3-management                                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   rabbitmq
f67b2276fbce        foobl/php:7.0-xdebug                                  "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp                                                                                     php70
ebc6096c4416        foobl/elasticsearch:5.5                               "/bin/bash bin/es-do…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:9250->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9350->9300/tcp                                               elasticsearch5
bc2cf3e80314        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:9260->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9360->9300/tcp                                               elasticsearch6
58088cdd49e4        foobl/php:7.1-xdebug                                  "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp                                                                                     php71
ceb89c760074        foobl/varnish:4.0                                     "/start.sh"              4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          80/tcp, 6082/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp                                                     varnish4
920d756cbcb7        mailhog/mailhog                                       "MailHog"                4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp                                               mailhog
9daeceefe68f        foobl/nginx                                           "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp                                                     nginx
70f71b5b2b2a        ebrown38/postgresql-tuned                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                                                       postgresql
6f0df7e4f627        elasticsearch:1.5                                     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                                             elasticsearch
3d02bdf3dc39        redis:alpine                                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                                                                       redis
651e79b3ae2e        foobl/varnish:3.0                                     "/srv/start.sh"          4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          6082/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                                               varnish3
e3787c986d8a        foobl/php:7-xdebug                                    "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp                                                                                     php7
361a50a8c261        ebrown38/mariadb                                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                                                                       db
4a47340e2796        foobl/elasticsearch:2                                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9220->9200/tcp                                                             elasticsearch2
080f9f0b828c        ebrown38/php7s                                        "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp
```

Running processes inside redis container:

```
/ # ps -a
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 redis     0:00 redis-server
   23 root      0:00 sh
   31 root      0:00 ps -a
```

sudo iptables -S:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o br-b9fecb964446 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-b9fecb964446 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-b9fecb964446 ! -o br-b9fecb964446 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-5d1cdbb894b4 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-5d1cdbb894b4 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-5d1cdbb894b4 ! -o br-5d1cdbb894b4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-5d1cdbb894b4 -o br-5d1cdbb894b4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-51f4978fc572 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-51f4978fc572 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-51f4978fc572 ! -o br-51f4978fc572 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-51f4978fc572 -o br-51f4978fc572 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-e86a1adbe04c -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-e86a1adbe04c -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-e86a1adbe04c ! -o br-e86a1adbe04c -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-e86a1adbe04c -o br-e86a1adbe04c -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.132/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.105/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.110/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.110/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.200/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8025 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.200/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1025 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.100/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.177/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.4/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.115/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 15672 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.115/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.136/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9300 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.3/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.130/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.135/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9300 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.136/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.135/32 ! -i br-b9fecb964446 -o br-b9fecb964446 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-b9fecb964446 ! -o br-b9fecb964446 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-5d1cdbb894b4 ! -o br-5d1cdbb894b4 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-51f4978fc572 ! -o br-51f4978fc572 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-e86a1adbe04c ! -o br-e86a1adbe04c -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-b9fecb964446 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-5d1cdbb894b4 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-51f4978fc572 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-e86a1adbe04c -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

docker network inspect util_devel:

```
[
{
    "Name": "util_devel",
    "Id": "b9fecb964446bf0b1b8a43b626e87505739b302ded010719ec46d544f7293f89",
    "Created": "2020-10-19T13:38:28.0368746-07:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/24"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "080f9f0b828cfbb85654a03f4ac1c888558d2170c63d2b6ea7a1f1c2607e7417": {
            "Name": "php7s",
            "EndpointID": "d1485564b4110ec59c27e59121743186e0857e9e4090b22cae5bf7325d692b69",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:ac",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.172/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "361a50a8c261030a06b61223873ee43d69bedcdc8e1670861a362df0dc3cc692": {
            "Name": "db",
            "EndpointID": "5e66a42f60cc5fc3d23da280b3a586729b609400201bacee77a9bacd1ec44e9b",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:69",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.105/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "3d02bdf3dc39862947c55fc954ff9e8a18641933986bce48de0156b2f8539c38": {
            "Name": "redis",
            "EndpointID": "2a71e69107cf2cd4b50bc8731e5fa195d92fe80d2229e5c6ef2ebc126df8781d",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:64",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.100/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "4a47340e2796eaa291de78af418bdb6233824537fcd8d737ec71a681cc46998a": {
            "Name": "elasticsearch2",
            "EndpointID": "bd502ba40483822230315c3f699752173d20f2c51dbab1ed433afa47e5dc8d4c",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:84",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.132/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "58088cdd49e4c99c887b28305e7bea14dd330ea1bd4d58b7e14e505ce55cb529": {
            "Name": "php71",
            "EndpointID": "96c01ac951f4b1771e8e588efd72e63012afcd38c946d6400459a292efb56c3b",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:ab",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.171/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "651e79b3ae2e74aff57a8a3cb1fc60047bc73a45bb87ac7c22d2802e39270adc": {
            "Name": "varnish3",
            "EndpointID": "07c8a8911133189937b497c26d4c4d4b39304f4c1c47ca9a4ac64d35f6c8342b",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "6f0df7e4f6277cca102e4b0def9225bf7e95d6e79cb0acff9469136dbc11b3fa": {
            "Name": "elasticsearch",
            "EndpointID": "b0f742d68dfc1f37c79f04c6664e8cf03857598ea827cc6043e3125763bc937b",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:82",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.130/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "70f71b5b2b2ad8df55826f56e1b03cad1f4590bb6961834bdef21d38cab197b7": {
            "Name": "postgresql",
            "EndpointID": "5e587520aa79c3523690d4fc2a8b15278c77e3a89b1786acd61987d58b089c60",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:b1",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.177/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "920d756cbcb7cab42ae3f004fafdd76def9736f4c9de8b91b948ddbd3c5412b7": {
            "Name": "mailhog",
            "EndpointID": "67926195e63791f05dd605196aa86e4b72b82eeb85d3fec643d20280f167bc37",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:c8",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.200/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "9daeceefe68fe8606102ee793183476f681ff7c833ffaa6dbc8da7d70e3ed16a": {
            "Name": "nginx",
            "EndpointID": "9684199b96aa6b7acde468188a06c51c28888fb49e7cf38d1838b7b7626b43a1",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:6e",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.110/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "bc2cf3e803142d5e0291a0211668b786b90df26fdd926a847be9e3acea431690": {
            "Name": "elasticsearch6",
            "EndpointID": "b7d79171385f483e39588e0274df8c9a2c143d20eab66c98feb8c6691905e43e",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:88",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.136/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "c6c56725172b01be91c756af5bf6cb7f7cffd90b94b65e84e42218bef8721615": {
            "Name": "php56",
            "EndpointID": "44a714c478ee3b621f35fdf19cb5f2109920d56054ac5b283084ea6fce437b5c",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:9c",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.156/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ceb89c760074cb038f435bfbb6b95e001d4418965d1193d3b20b450215bdd196": {
            "Name": "varnish4",
            "EndpointID": "da294cc12c46b426c93bc55ede19f2a79d1c2eb4ecca08c1b90dac51ffb64056",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.4/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "e3787c986d8af22eb7b9aee9fee72ec1215bedf103fd3aeff5093cb0c5e4a245": {
            "Name": "php7",
            "EndpointID": "1bcd2fdce04864b9013990535094d0a0fd8ed59323e447b14836f1e2ccf91ab9",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:11",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.17/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ebc6096c441625274be37bbe80f0fbf459577ac8f84bc2e41e4b5056bcd7b66d": {
            "Name": "elasticsearch5",
            "EndpointID": "7abd1fc5d810a42fec5e16e48d2a979600b8aa6f542ba29a8bc5b49441600eba",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:87",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.135/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "f67b2276fbce4179b2065c6eb15d56381f9dc8abfe149c61111e8c61b03d0596": {
            "Name": "php70",
            "EndpointID": "cd1c7ecea3a826e0c66c8f0c8423df7c5ec08457ca67f55ffe1e6b60f8b7caa1",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:aa",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.170/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "fdc76ffe6efb73c4a3181ac0b2053559b91bcfa13dea8793961de53d514265a5": {
            "Name": "rabbitmq",
            "EndpointID": "621da68d91bf7c4757571bd0ed7c791c748acf0e8116101fcc3d5cad2d0e4060",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:73",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.115/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "devel",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "util",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.0"
    }
}
```

]

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   *.localhost
127.0.1.1   eric-desktop
172.19.0.200 mailhog
172.19.0.100 redis
172.19.0.105 db
172.19.0.177 postgres
172.19.0.110 nginx
172.19.0.115 rabbitmq
172.19.0.17 php7
172.19.0.187 php74
172.19.0.172 php7s
172.19.0.170 php70
172.19.0.171 php71
172.19.0.156 php56
172.19.0.130 elasticsearch
172.19.0.132 elasticsearch2
172.19.0.135 elasticsearch5
172.19.0.136 elasticsearch6
172.19.0.3 varnish3
172.19.0.4 varnish4
```

Comment: It would help to post the actual output of the checks you ran.

Comment: Ok, I added the output for all of the checks.